# Update with counter with group by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus

I have a table `T1` and which looks like this

```
DATUM   ID  NAME    ROW_COUNT

2/14/2021   101 ALEX    
2/14/2021   100 SHAUN   
2/14/2021   102 SCOTT   
2/15/2021   100 SHAUN   
2/15/2021   101 ALEX    
2/15/2021   102 SCOTT   
2/16/2021   100 SHAUN   
2/16/2021   101 ALEX    
2/16/2021   102 SCOTT
```

which have column `datum` , `ID`, `Name`, `Row_Count` I want update Counter like this

```
DATUM   ID  NAME    ROW_COUNT

2/14/2021   101 ALEX    1
2/14/2021   100 SHAUN   1
2/14/2021   102 SCOTT   1
2/15/2021   100 SHAUN   2
2/15/2021   101 ALEX    2
2/15/2021   102 SCOTT   2
2/16/2021   100 SHAUN   3
2/16/2021   101 ALEX    3
2/16/2021   102 SCOTT   3
```

What I tried like this

```
UPDATE DAILY_PRODUCTION
SET DOC_ID=DOC_ID+1
GROUP BY DATUM;
```

But not worked any one knows please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest *not* doing this update, but rather using the following select with `DENSE_RANK`:

```sql
SELECT DATUM, ID, NAME, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY DATUM) ROW_COUNT
FROM DAILY_PRODUCTION
ORDER BY DATUM, ID;
```

The reason for not wanting to maintain the `ROW_COUNT` column is that it might be derived data.  As such, you could be forced to run this update multiple times as the data changes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it will be needed once after that data will be entered through proper form where this field is already set. and is there any way to update that because otherwise I have to made changes every where and post this query to every where Lot of thanks in advance

Comment: @aws ... playing the devil's advocate, you would still have to re-run the update any time you add new data or change existing data.  If you need this often, then consider creating a materialized view, and also tune the query with appropriate indices.

Comment: Thanks no I dont want to play with Devil's advocate its ok :) always cheers and blessed